Azure Function throws exception: OnStarting cannot be set because the response has already started
The following exception is thrown when returning on a HttpResponseData from an Azure Function using .NET 8.0 and set it up to as an isolated process.
OnStarting cannot be set because the response has already started
When calling the following code:
[Function(nameof(Test))]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "put", Route = null)] HttpRequestData request)
{
    var message = "This is a test message";
    this.logger.LogError(messag);
    var badRequestResponse = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    await badRequestResponse.WriteStringAsync(messag);
    return badRequestResponse;
}


After hours of research and trimming my project to its bare bones where nothing was left (i.e. removed all third-part libraries, removed all DI from constructor and program.cs), I eventually figured out what the problem was.
I thought it would be good to upgrade all Azure libraries to their latest versions and this was a costly and time consuming mistake which I only wish I had spotted sooner.
When Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore is set to use the latest version (1.3.0) at the time of writing this, it will throw the mentioned exception i.e. OnStarting cannot be set because the response has already started when creating a response and trying to return it.
The second I downgraded this to its previous version i.e. 1.2.1, the problem got resolved.
Hope this helps other!
PS: I've raised the issue with Microsoft on GitHub. Hopefully they'll be able to reproduce it as I have and will provide a fix in the next patch!
